# PHP: Dynamic object property causing error in OSvC

Tags: php, object

I have the following code which gets an object based on the person logged into Oracle Service Cloud (heavily modified codeigniter on Zend)

```
RNCPHP\ConnectAPI::getCurrentContext()->ApplicationContext = "Get contact information";
$c = Array();
$contact = json_encode($this->CI->session->getProfile(), true);
$contact = json_decode($contact, true);
$uid = $contact['c_id']['value'];
$contact = RNCPHP\Contact::fetch($uid);

$d = explode('.',$contact->CustomFields->c->department);
try {
    foreach ($contact->CustomFields->c as $k) {
        $a[$k] = $contact->CustomFields->c->{$k}; // ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    }
}
catch (\Exception $err ){
    echo $err->getMessage();
}
```

The $contact record gets retrieved but it makes use of lazy loading so I have to specifically call what I need

> Instantiating or using a Connect PHP primary object does not cause a
>   read from the database until the ID is set and a property that is not
>   a primary key is read. Exceptions to this are the fetch() method which
>   will validate the IDs given to it, and the find() and first() methods
>   which perform searches upon the database. However, using the resulting
>   objects will not 'hit' the database until a non-key property is read
>   for the first time.

However, all I am getting is: `There has been an error with your request.`

Any advice?

Thanks